# Getting error about a required member

Tags: visual-studio, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows 8.1 application in Visual Studio 2013 to create an Excel Sheet at run time. Visual Studio doesn't show any error, but when I run the app, there is a run time error that is :

> Error 1   Missing compiler required member
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.LCIDConversionAttribute..ctor'    D:\GS\Projects\excel\excel\CSC  excel

Here is my CS code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace excel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workbooks = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            workbook = workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Value1";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Value2";
            worksheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Addition";
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, there is no red line shown in VS-2013 for error.
I added references for Excel : `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can not automate office from a store app.  I would look at using something like syncfusion's docio if you want to create a spread sheet

Comment: I had try with syncfusion.core dll, then there is another error. To solve that error i download something Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base dll then there is another error. To solve that error i download Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and obviously here is an error.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution ?